# How to get Context for SharedPreferences without extending any super class?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-context

I am trying to write a code in Android to get context for `SharedPrefrences` from my parent class without extending to Super Class.

**My Code :**

```
public class TestClass
{


    static Context mContext; //class variable

TestClass(Context context)
{

    mContext = context;

}

    String text = null;

    SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Status", 0);

    text = pref.getString("Number",null);

    Log.d(" Text Result : ", text);

}
```

I am getting error in **getApplicationContext()** that no able to find **getApplicationContext()** in TestClass.

Please let me know how can I get the context and I will use it `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 1):

If this really is your code it can't work at all. Because the global fields will be initialized before the constructor is called. That's why

```
SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Status", 0);
```

is called before the constructor init the mContext.

Init your fields in the constructor after you have init the mContext field by passing it from a class which derives from Context (Activity, Service...)

```
public class TestClass
{

    static Context mContext; //class variable
    String text;
    SharedPreferences pref;

    TestClass(Context context)
    {

        mContext = context;
        pref = mContext.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Status", 0);
        text = pref.getString("Number",null);
        Log.d(" Text Result : ", text);
    }
}
```

Call this in your Activity:

```
TestClass tc = new TestClass(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you cannot do this(cannot get application context of a context):

```
SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Status", 0);
```

you should use it like this:

```
SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences("Status",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Additionally makes no sense to use this without an Activity?